# How to submit invalid XML through QTP Web Services

Tags: xml, web-services, qtp

I am trying to submit an XML using the web services tool in QTP. I can submit valid XML's with no problem but when I try to submit an invalid XML for negative testing (such as setting an elements value to 'XXX' when it should be a valid date). I keep getting an error on the line

Set submitXMLRequest = WebServices(webservicename).submitRequest(subReq)

The error says "There is an error in XML document(92,8)
Exception from: mscorlib
String was not recognized as a valid Date Time

How do I prevent the XML's data from being validated before the request is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hitting the web service through QTP without using the web services tool? I run all of our web services through through QTP/UFT without that portion of the suite and I can submit whatever I want to our APIs.

I've had to check the response after submitting malformed XML/JSON data to ensure that checks were being completed prior to it being processed by the main service and that sounds like what you are trying to do.

Not having actually used that tool, could it be validating your request prior to submitting it? If that's the case, it may not be possible to inject bad request data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using UFT API Module. UFT parses the XML and hence you will not be able to enter XML special characters & and < in data portion. You can use below function to do xml request post. This is what I am using in my project now.

```
public static string HttpRequest(string url, string xml)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;

        httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        httpWebRequest.Timeout = 10000;

        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);

            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

            using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            httpWebResponse.Close();
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception ("Error");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (httpWebResponse != null)
                {
                    httpWebResponse.Close();
                    httpWebResponse = null;
                }

                httpWebRequest = null;
            }
            return response;
        }
```